# https error in nodejs?

Tags: node.js, ssl, https, ubuntu-14.04

I have installed SSL certificated on ubutunu. 
this is not self generated certificates.
I have implemented code

```
var sslOptions = {
  key: fs.readFileSync('/etc/ssl/private/private.key'),
  cert: fs.readFileSync('/etc/ssl/certs/STAR_certs.crt'),
  //ca: fs.readFileSync('/etc/ssl/certs/AddTrustExternalCARoot.crt'),
  requestCert: true,
  rejectUnauthorized: false
};
```

and i do confirm all above files are present. and STAR_certs.crt is having root permissions.

And i got following error now

> Error: error:0906D06C:PEM routines:PEM_read_bio:no start line
>       at Object.exports.createCredentials (crypto.js:100:17)
>       at Server (tls.js:1130:28)
>       at new Server (https.js:35:14)
>       at Object.exports.createServer (https.js:54:10)

Any idea.  I dnt have any pem file

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to check that your private.key and STAR_certs.crt files are in format, supported by OpenSSL (which is PEM). If they are not, you need to convert those files. You will find conversion instructions in other StackOverflow questions and answers ( I don't know in which format your files are now, so I can't direct you to any particular answer).